# How do I embed KQL or FQL in a URL for SharePoint 2013?

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to create a URL to search the tokenizedURL managed property.  Something like this:

https://XXXXXX/EnterpriseSearchCenter/Pages/default.aspx?k=TokenizedURL:mySearchTerm

but I can't seem to get the URL format correct

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

http://yoursharepointSite.com/_api/search/query?YourProperty:Contains("keyword")

If it doesn't work, check some other things too:

Go into the Sharepoint Central Admin page, Application Management, Manage Services, click on your search service, under Search Administration select Search Schema. Find the property that you are trying to search against and click on it.

Check the "Searchable" block, and make sure the "Retrievable" block is also set.  Also take note of the data type because that will affect how you can search against it.

"Safe" affects whether you can hit it without authenticating.

Comment: I found this:  http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/limiting-search-results-by-exact-time.html

Comment: Making it retrievable might be necessary too:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/227323/managed-property-after-full-crawl-is-still-empty